# get bezierPath of parametric eq given gain,freq,and q

Tags: macos, cocoa, bezier, equalizer

i have to draw a GUI in xcode cocoa app, for a parametric equalizer which i have gains, freq, and q paramiters.
My idea is to use NSBezierPath but i have no ideas how to get the points to build it.
Some suggestions ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use **NSBezierPath moveToPoint**, **lineToPoint** and **curveToPoint** functions. Please check this link http://www.knowstack.com/nsbezierpath-curves-and-graphs/

Comment: i know ho to use NSBezierPath , the question is : how to calculate the points for a given parametric equalizer ?

Comment: Then, you have to explain what this "parametric equalizer" is.

Comment: in this link there is an explanation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equalization_(audio)#Parametric_equalizer end this is a graphic example http://bedroomproducersblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/eq4-cis.jpg

Comment: It is doubtful that anyone who is unfamiliar with a parametric equalizer would have an answer to this question.